# Правильно ли сверстано на html5?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, html5, инспекция-кода

Решил перейти на HTML5, и вот первая верстка - websterjoy.tk. Хочу узнать, какие теги html5 я использовал там где нужно, какие не по месту назначения, и вообще оценку верстки. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: все отлично, вот только section местами надо бы на article заменить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вижу что вы учли прошлые мои замечания и в этот раз вёрстка выполнена качественно, за исключением нескольких замечаний:

- Я так понял, что вы нам показываете макет карточки товара? То естественным образом будет  обернуть название товара в h1, а не в h2. Вы используете h1 для выражения "Каталог товаров", что тоже не хорошо. Если честно не понял предназначение этого выражения для данной страницы, но это уже к вопрос к дизайнеру, что он имел ввиду. Лучше обернуть его в span какой-нибудь, а не заголовок. Опять же, совет с точки зрения и SEO.
- Вижу вы используете спрайт для объединения мелких картинок, хорошо! Но почему объединили не все картинки?
- <a onclick="look('div1', this);">...</a> - это нехорошо. Вынесите логику в отдельный скрипт или блок <script>...</script>
- Придерживайтесь одного стиля: либо обычный html, либо строгий (xhtml). А то у вас где то ../> а где-то просто >.
- Маленькое пожелание: коль уж у вас на странице есть ссылки на skype и icq, то можно слегка упростить пользователям жизнь [следующим образом](http://www.kobzarev.com/programming/links-to-icq-and-skype.html).

**UPDATE:**
Ну раз уж вы используете на сайте jQuery, то напишу скрипт с её помощью:

```
$(function() {
    $('.turn').on('click', function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#div1').toggle();

        var text = $(this).text();
        text = (text == 'Свернуть ↑') ? 'Развернуть ↓' : 'Свернуть ↑';
        $(this).text(text);
    });
});
```

В ссылке с классом 'turn' уберите атрибут onClick и добавьте атрибут href="#".

Comment: Спасибо снова за советы! Поисправляю. Только на счет JS, можно, пожалуйста, подробнее, что куда вынести? скрипт то из сети, а в JS не понимаю ничего

Comment: Все работает! Спасибо.